# Incrementing Values inside an if statement

Tags: c#

I found out that I can increase the value of a variable inside an if statement like so:

```
int limit = 100;
int nrCopies = 2;
int maxValue = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
    if((nTotal += (nrCopies)) > maxValue)
        break;
}
```

This works, and I became acostumed to do this, but I want to know if it is a good practice to do so, since I don't want to get bad habits unnecessarily

Comment: This is a generic best practice question. This is not particularly helpful as a Python programmer would say no, but a JavaScript programmer would say yes. Ultimately we don't have enough context to know if this is good or not.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is quite questionable.

Imagine you never saw this code before, and are trying to understand it, would this make it easier to understand or harder? I say harder.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GeorgeBarwood answer, full stop.

[Next note @ Peilonrayz comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244725/incrementing-values-inside-an-if-statement#comment480470_244725) *...we don't have enough context*

**If the contex or intent is** to emphasize "Increment until reaching the max value", or better: "make this many copies", then use a `while` loop.

```
int total = 0;

while (total <= maxValue) {
   total += nCopies;
}
```